# Does RGBDSLAM use QT for UI?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand the source better. Does RGBDSLAM use QT for UI?

https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228961/does-rgbdslam-use-qt-for-ui?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it looks like it does. If you search through the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/indigo/CMakeLists.txt) for 'QT", you can see which files are part of the UI.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. It is defined in qt_gui.h/cpp. The 3D visualization is also based on qt and defined in glviewer.h/cpp.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2